# Where is the php_error.log file in Acquia Dev Desktop?

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I'm having problem with a site installed with Acquia Dev Desktop, but I can't find the php_error.log file to see the errors. There is nothing inside the DevDesktop folder and I can't see anything in the Software Preference.

Where is the php_error.log file in Acquia Dev Desktop?

Comment: Have you tried looking through the error log provided by Drupal UI?

Comment: @NoSssweat the site shows the error message that only says that there is a problem in all the pages

Comment: Did you add this line `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` to your settings.php file?

Comment: If you're using XAMPP take a look at [Where does PHP's error log reside in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp)

Comment: @NoSssweat I come from found the answer, thanks for your time ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just checked in my installation of DevDesktop and found that my PHP logs are located in `/Applications/DevDesktop/apache/logs/error_log`.

Although it says Apache logs, PHP errors get logged there as well.

You can find the log locations via 'Preferences' => 'Logs'. DevDesktop version 2 (Apr 13, 2017).

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, you need to search the php.ini file inside the php version folder that you are using. Open the file and search for this line:

```
;error_log = php_errors.log
```

Delete the `;` to activate the error logging, then you will have:

```
error_log = php_errors.log
```

Save the file and restart your server and the file will be created in your site root folder.